# UML relationships

Tags: uml, class-diagram, relationships

Could someone explain to me if the relation in this class diagram is a "dependency" or "association" relationship and why?

[image]

*I cannot edit the picture. The terms translate into English as follows: Pessoa = Person; Agencia = Office; Conta = Account*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community The question is a basic and very specific UML question with all the informations required for answering it (see page 207 of the UML 2.5.1 specifications for the answer).

Answer (score 1):

This diagram represents an [association class](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/associationclass.html). This means that a `Person` is associated with an `Office`, but that each instance of the association (link in UML jargon) is at the same time an instance (i.e. object) of the class `Account`. The association class is graphically attached to the association with a dotted line.  The name of the association and the name of the class must be the same.  For a practical example, see also [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62094457/3723423).

***Caution 1**: association classes shall not be confused with [ternary associations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46917458/3723423).  Ternary associations are represented with a diamond to which all the associated classes are attached (with plain lines, not dotted lines), and there can be a different multiplicity at  the three ends of the associated classes (in the binary association class, there are only two multiplicities, one at each end).*

***Caution 2**: this diagram does imply a dependency but it does not represent a dependency.  A dependency would be shown with a doted line with an open arrow head at one end.*